# INSERT query not adding at all

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

I have striped my insert statement and rebuilt it thinking that would solve the problem, it has not.
The statement will not add any data at all, can any one see why its not working?

**index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">

    Name Of Band:</br>
    <input type="text" name="Name" /><br />

    Show Name:</br>
    <input type="text" name="show" /><br />

    Venue:</br>
    <input type="text" name="Venue" /><br />

    Category:</br>
    <input type="text" name="Category" /><br />

    Price:</br>
    <input type="text" name="price" /><br />

    Stock:</br>
    <input type="text" name="Stock" /><br />

    Infomation:</br>
    <input type="text" name="infomation" /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Add Band"/>

</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
     <?php
require 'core/init.php';
$Name = $_REQUEST["Name"];
$show = $_REQUEST["show"];
$Venue = $_REQUEST["Venue"];
$Category = $_REQUEST["Category"];
$price = $_REQUEST["price"];
$Stock = $_REQUEST["Stock"];
$infomation = $_REQUEST["infomation"];


$query = "INSERT INTO `bands` (`Name`, `show`, `Venue`, `Category`, `price`, `Stock`, `infomation`) VALUES ('$Name', '$show', '$Venue', '$Category', '$price', '$Stock', '$infomation')";

mysql_query ($query, $linkme)
    or die ("could not add to database");
    header("location:admin.php");
?>
```

**schema**

```
     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bands`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bands` (
  `Band_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `show` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `Venue` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `infomation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Band_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

nothing wrong with connection as many insert update and delete query use it.

Comment: Sidenote: Your code is [Open to SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: How would I prevent that ?

Comment: Click the link I provided to you in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks, did not see it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is fine.

Your table has multiple fields that are declared `not null`, such as `stock` and `information` and so on.  These have no default values, so your `insert` is failing.

You have several choices:

- Change the columns to allow NULL
- Provide values for them in the `insert`
- Provide default values

Comment: `Your query is fine`?? Unless the band name is something like `'n sync` of course...

Comment: The query is not causing the `insert` problem.  You are right, it is subject to SQL injection.  I'm surprised that comment hasn't yet appeared on the question.

Comment: I will look into fixing the sql injection security once I have the insert working. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hmm have updated my question, still not inserting for some reason.

Comment: Could it be because `price` and `stock` are numbers?  Also, it would help if you printed out the SQL *after* variable substitution.

Comment: OK I understand, I will try and change.